# useEffect with redux state and dep gets executed whenever there is some other change in redux state

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a 2 table components displaying a list of users in Org1 and Org2. I maintain both the list in redix state.

redux:

```
{
org1: [{}, ...],
org1Filters: {}
org2: [{}, ...],
org2Filters: {}
}
```

My component uses useEffect to call API and get the users from both the orgs

```
function Component() {

useEffect(() => {
 getOrg1Users(org1Filters).
 then((result) => {
 dispatch(updateOrg1Users(result))
});
}, [org1Filters]);


useEffect(() => {
 getOrg2Users(org2Filters).
 then((result) => {
 dispatch(updateOrg2Users(result))
 });
}, [org2Filters]);

return(
<>
<Org1table/>
Org2Table/>
</>
);

}
```

So baiscally, whenever the filters change for Org1 and Org2, I want the API to trigger and get the list of users. But when I update org1 filters API call for both the orgs is triggered.

I figured that this might be due to the update in redux state when filters change (as the redux will return a new object after each update). The useEffect is comparing object instance instead of object values.

I solved this issue by doing this

```
const prevOrg2Filters = usePrevious(org2Filters);
useEffect(() => {
 if(!_isEqual(prevOrg2Filters, org2Filters)){
  getOrg2Users(org2Filters).
  then((result) => {
  dispatch(updateOrg2Users(result))
 });
}
}, [org2Filters]);
```

Can someone confirm my understanding? Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

When you update your state in redux store, you clone the rest of the state variables and update the required state, as a result the **reference of org2Filters changes**, causing the `useEffect` to run again.

Now one solution to solve this is to `usePrevious` and and compare the previous and current values which is a perfectly good solution

Another solution is to take out the `org1Filters` and `org2Filters` into separate reducers

```
combineReducers({
   org1Filters,
   org2Filters,
   filtersData,
});
```

Doing this will ensure that the reference of org2Filters object doesn't change when you update org1Filters or filtersData and viceVersa.